# jQuery: Select tag expect one id

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Code:**

```
<select id="avoid_id">
   <option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('select :not(avoid_id)').change(some_function); // not working
```

I want to execute same function on all `<select>` tag change except with id `avoid_id`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: use #avoid_id in not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$('select:not(#avoid_id)')` as `:not` is a css selector and it comes together with the element so use `select:not` and the parameter for `:not()` is the id value so use `#avoid_id` inside that:

```js
$('select:not(#avoid_id)').change(some_function);

function some_function() {
  console.log('changed');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="avoid_id">
   <option value="All">All</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```